# Getting the android username stored in the phone

Tags: android

I am writing an application that requires to retrieve the android username username@gmail.com from the phone.  I have been looking at AccountManager class.  This is what I have for now in my code.

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

    Account[] accounts =
    accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    String email="";
    email=accountManager.getUserData(accounts[0], accountManager.KEY_USERDATA);
```

However, I am getting a caller uid 10085 is different than the authenticator's uid exception.
Anyone knows how to do it?

PS. I don't need password or authentication token, I just need the username.

Answer (score 2):

Username is available to you; just use:

`String email = accounts[0].name;`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission set in your manifest file? See the [docs](http://d.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)) on the getAccountsByType() method:

> This method requires the caller to hold the permission GET_ACCOUNTS.

Make sure your application manifest has this line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`